# RateLimiter With Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rate-limiting

Here my requirement is,

I've a REST API which takes request parameter, from this request we get appId, userid, and IP address(of the request coming from) and i need to rate limit 5 requests per second(for the given key combination).

I have this sample code which restricts the user to allow maximum 5 requests/second. it works fine when there is only one user sending more than 5 requests then, it allows only 5 request/second and for remaining request it throws error "Too many request". but when there is more than one user(say 5) and each user is sending more than 5 requests/second then it is not able to limit the rate for the users(here all the 5 users should be able to send 5 requests/second) ie, total 25 requests should be success and remaining request should throw error like "too many request". 
please suggest me where I am missing.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private int CACHESIZE = 1000;
    private int rateRequests = 5;

    private ConcurrentMap<Object, Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(CACHESIZE).build().asMap();

    private RateLimiter rateLimiter;

    HomeController() {
        rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(rateRequests);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData(HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (!preCheck(request)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return "get userdata from data base";
        }
    }

    private boolean preCheck(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String key = request.getParameter("userId") + request.getParameter("applicationId") + request.getRemoteAddr();
        RateLimiter rateLimiter = getRateLimiter();
        if (cache.containsKey(key)) {
            rateLimiter = (RateLimiter) cache.get(key);
        } else {
            cache.put(key, rateLimiter);
        }

        boolean allow = rateLimiter.tryAcquire();
        if (!allow) {
            System.out.println("Too many request");
        }
        return allow;
    }

    public RateLimiter getRateLimiter() {
        return rateLimiter;
    }

}


import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RateLimitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RateLimitTest limitTest = new RateLimitTest();
        limitTest.scheduleJob();
    }

    static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    private void scheduleJob() {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // getUserData("user1");
                            getUserData(randomGen(5));

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private String randomGen(int count) {
        String value = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (count-- != 0) {
            int charIndex = (int) (Math.random() * value.length());
            builder.append(value.charAt(charIndex));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String getUserData(String user) {
        return "call rest api( /getData ) to get the user data";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because all requests share one rate limiter, you should create a rate limiter per key. try this :

```
private boolean preCheck(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String key = request.getParameter("userId") + request.getParameter("applicationId") + request.getRemoteAddr();
    RateLimiter rl = cache.get(key);
    if(rl == null){
       rl = RateLimiter.create(rateRequests);
       RateLimiter old = cache.putIfAbsent(key , rl);
       if(old !=null){
            rl = old;
       }
    }
    boolean allow = rl.tryAcquire();
    if (!allow) {
        System.out.println("Too many request");
    }
    return allow;
}
```

do not forget to remove the definition of property *rateLimiter*